# PHP button name change

Tags: html

This is my code, and its showing a "Submit Query" button, how can I change it's name ?

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $output = shell_exec('cd /home && ls');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="YOUR BUTTON NAME">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a value attribute

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send form">
```